# What is a smoothness map?

Tags: materials, pbr

Is a smoothness map the same thing as a roughness map?

For example:

[image: Smoothness Map]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smoothness is the opposite of roughness. If you have a smoothness map you can use the "Invert" node to plug it into a roughness input. You can find it under (`shift`+ `a`) *Add* -> *Color* -> *Invert*.

For example:

[image: Example]